# PyInstaller ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, pyqt5

I am still very new to Python. I am using:

- Windows 10, 64bit
- Python 3.5.3
- PyInstaller 3.2.1

I tried to package my first GUI test-application with PyInstaller. I used

`pyinstaller --onedir testgui.py`

for this. The resulting application didn't run. When I tried to run the `.exe` file through the command promp, it returned the following message:

```
C:\PythonProjects\firstGUI\dist\testgui>testgui.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 573, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
ImportError: DLL load failed: [Module not found in german....] .
Failed to execute script pyi_rth_qt5plugins
```

These are all the imports I did in my very short script:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
```

What am I doing wrong? If it helps, I can post all the WARNING lines I got during the packaging process.

**EDIT:**

I received a couple of those `WARNING: lib not found` entries in the log during the packaging. Here is the full packaging log:

```
C:\PythonProjects\firstGUI>pyinstaller --onedir testgui.py
91 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2.1
91 INFO: Python: 3.5.3
91 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0
92 INFO: wrote C:\PythonProjects\firstGUI\testgui.spec
93 INFO: UPX is not available.
95 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\PythonProjects\\firstGUI', 'C:\\PythonProjects\\firstGUI']
95 INFO: checking Analysis
95 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
95 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
97 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
98 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2321 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
2323 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe
2539 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
2588 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
2635 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
2682 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
2729 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
2778 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
2826 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
2875 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
2922 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
2968 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
3016 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
3062 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
3111 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
3158 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
3205 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
3253 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
3300 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
3346 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
3394 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
3442 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
3489 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
3535 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
3584 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
3630 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
3678 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
3741 INFO: Caching module hooks...
3745 INFO: Analyzing C:\PythonProjects\firstGUI\testgui.py
3773 INFO: Loading module hooks...
3773 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
3946 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
3997 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
4301 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
4302 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
4304 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
4377 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.Qt.py"...
4378 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
4380 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtPrintSupport.py"...
4449 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
4450 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
4453 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_qt5.py'
4455 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py'
4460 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
4519 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qoffscreen.dll
4569 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qoffscreen.dll
4627 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\printsupport\windowsprintersupport.dll
4685 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5PrintSupport.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\printsupport\windowsprintersupport.dll
4734 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\printsupport\windowsprintersupport.dll
4789 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qicns.dll
4839 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qicns.dll
4898 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtga.dll
4948 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtga.dll
5012 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
5086 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
5145 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Svg.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\iconengines\qsvgicon.dll
5195 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\iconengines\qsvgicon.dll
5245 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\iconengines\qsvgicon.dll
5303 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qico.dll
5353 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qico.dll
5410 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Svg.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qsvg.dll
5460 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qsvg.dll
5511 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qsvg.dll
5568 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
5619 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
5678 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
5728 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
5789 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qwebp.dll
5840 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qwebp.dll
5895 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qminimal.dll
5945 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qminimal.dll
6003 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qwbmp.dll
6053 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qwbmp.dll
6115 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qgif.dll
6165 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of C:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qgif.dll
6319 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtCore.pyd
6383 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Widgets.dll dependency of c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtPrintSupport.pyd
6434 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtPrintSupport.pyd
6489 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5PrintSupport.dll dependency of c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtPrintSupport.pyd
6538 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtPrintSupport.pyd
6593 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtGui.pyd
6644 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtGui.pyd
6703 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Widgets.dll dependency of c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtWidgets.pyd
6753 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtWidgets.pyd
6808 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtWidgets.pyd
6915 INFO: Looking for eggs
6915 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python35.dll
6916 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
6922 INFO: Warnings written to C:\PythonProjects\firstGUI\build\testgui\warntestgui.txt
6930 INFO: checking PYZ
6931 INFO: Building PYZ because out00-PYZ.toc is non existent
6931 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\PythonProjects\firstGUI\build\testgui\out00-PYZ.pyz
7387 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\PythonProjects\firstGUI\build\testgui\out00-PYZ.pyz completed successfully.
7394 INFO: checking PKG
7394 INFO: Building PKG because out00-PKG.toc is non existent
7395 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
7411 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg completed successfully.
7413 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\xyz\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
7413 INFO: checking EXE
7413 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
7414 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
7415 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\PythonProjects\firstGUI\build\testgui\testgui.exe
7421 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc completed successfully.
7425 INFO: checking COLLECT
7425 INFO: Building COLLECT because out00-COLLECT.toc is non existent
7426 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc
7608 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc completed successfully.
```

Comment: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/If-Things-Go-Wrong

Comment: @StephenRauch Thanks, but I have already looked at that and did not find it very helpful. Maybe I am just not experienced enough with this, maybe I am just thick, but I have no Idea how exactly to "use the .spec-file" or "implement a new hook". I would appreciate any actual attempt to help me out. I've never done this before.

Comment: OK, I can try to help, but will need specific info as called out at the link.  In the above case, it is failing to find a DLL.  Did you run on the same machine you built on?  Also know that QT is one of the modules that is often hard to get right.  Also suggest you look at the pyinstaller bug tracker, and see if there is anything there of value for your situation.

Comment: @StephenRauch Thanks for trying! Yes, I tried to run it on the same machine I built it on. The program itself works fine in Python. It is literally just a widget with some text fields and a few buttons. I posted the packaging log below my original post above. I will attempt to check whether everything was packaged in the way described on their site and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the missing files on your drive and add their file path either to your environment variables Path data (Control Panel → System → Advanced System Settings → Environment Variables) or build with:

```
pyinstaller --paths yourpathshere app.py
```

For example, my project finds Qt5Core.dll and co as follows:

```
pyinstaller --paths C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin app.py
```

Comment: I have same problem as the OP and tried to search for those files but they are not found on the system.